# Error por tamaño al subir tema wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando subir un tema de Wordpress pero me sale este error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 147508414 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0 
El enlace que has seguido ha caducado.
```

He intentado cambiar en php.ini el valor de upload_max_filesize a 200M pero aún así persiste el error. ¿Qué debería cambiar para que permita la subida?

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en local o en un servidor? Si tras aplicar ese cambio a `php.ini` sigues sin poder subir el theme, puede ser que tu hosting tenga aplicado un límite a nivel de servidor. En ese caso, debes contactar con ellos.

Otros ficheros donde se pueden establecer los límites de subida, además del `php.ini` son `wp-config.php` y `.htaccess`.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en local. ¿Cual de los ficheros tiene preferencia? ¿php.ini, wp-config o htaccess? Y... ¿que valores se deberian cambiar?

Comment: ¿Has probado a reiniciar el servicio `Apache`? Es el que controla `php` y el que debe de "enterarse" de los nuevos cambios.

Comment: Perfecto. Cambio en php.ini de upload_max_filesize: de 2 a 2000  y post_max_size: de 8 a 800 y despues reiniciar Xampp
upload_max_filesize=2000M 
post_max_size=800M
la clave es tambien reiniciar como apuntaste. Gracias!

Comment: Si te ha funcionado, escríbelo como respuesta de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado: he cambiado en `php.ini` el valor de `upload_max_filesize`: de 2 a 2000 y el valor de  `post_max_size`: de 8 a 800 y después he reiniciado Xampp.

Resumen:

1. upload_max_filesize=2000M
2. post_max_size=800M
3. Reinicio de Xampp